# Flex using assql to connect to database, Flex - Security Sandbox violation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, crossdomain.xml, cross-domain-policy

I write a small flex project that connect to local database

the code is below:

```
    _dbData=new DataBaseData();
    _dbData.username="root";
    _dbData.password="woxnsk";
    _dbData.host="192.168.2.225";
    _dbData.port=3306;
    _dbData.database="query";
    _db=new MyDataBase(_dbData);
    _db.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnected);
    _db.connect();

    _isDBConnecting=true;
```

the project works well in flex builder,then I deployed it in my wamp server and something went wrong.

I can access the databse when I use the url like  localhost/myproject/login.html
but if I change the localhost into 127.0.0.1 or the ip 192.168.2.225, it failed to connect to database , and the error is Security Sandbox violation.

> Error #2044: unhandled ioError: text=Error #2048: Security Sandbox
>   violation.:http://192.168.2.225/bin-debug/QuestionCollecter.swf cannot
>   load data from 192.168.2.225:3306

I have put the  crossdomain.xml in the root directory of my server (C:\wamp\www or C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\ROOT)
the crossdomain.xml file is :

```
    <xml version="1.0"?>
    <cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

it does not work....so is there anything wrong?  Can anyone help me~

Answer (score 1):

1) You can check `allowScriptAccess` and `allowNetworking` options for embedding your swf into a page:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=wrapper_13.html

Make sure to grant unrestricted access to your swf.

2) You can extract your server address from `url` property of your application.

3) You can watch with `Charles` or `HTTPAnalyzer` what happens with `crossdomain.xml` requests from your application and if wamp makes this file avaliable for all IPs.

4) Does your database allow non-local connections?

Comment: Thanks for you advise! I found that my 843 port was occupied by another program, so i terminated it and wrote a servlet listening to 843 port ,and the problem is gone!